# Insertar bandera en listview Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, listview, edittext

Tengo un listview el cual lleno con `Arrayadapater` personalizado con datos que obtengo de mi bd SQLite.

El detalle es que yo necesito insertar una bandera o un identificador en cada detalle del `listview` que me muestre ya por ejemplo el `listview` me puede mostrar 4 renglones con sus detalles y hay un `edittext` el cual el usuario ingresa una cantidad, entonces el usuario puede que solo ingrese una cantidad en el primer renglón o los demás los deje en blanco, entonces yo tengo un for donde recorro mi `array` y hago una suma y después aplico el pago, el detalle es cuando aplico el pago me afecta todos los renglones y no debe de ser así, dejo mi código:

Método donde se recoge mi `array` y hago la suma y hago *update* a mis tablas

```
public void LLenarDetalle()

{
    boolean PagoCeros=false;

    boolean Activo=false;

    String Referencia = "", Folio = "";

    int Cliente = 0;

    Double Factor=0.0, Importe=0.0, Descuento=0.0, SubTotal=0.0, Total=0.0, IVA=0.0,Retencion1=0.0,Retencion2=0.0,IEPS=0.0, ISH=0.0, Financiamiento=0.0, SaldoC = 0.0, SaldoV = 0.0;

    Double DFactor=0.0;

    for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++) {



        if (((((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0) && (PagoCeros==false)) || ((((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado==0) && (PagoCeros==true)))
        {
                            DFactor = ((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado / ((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total;
                            Importe += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Importe*DFactor);   //Importe
                            Financiamiento +=  (Double)0.0;  //Financiamiento
                            Descuento += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Descuento*DFactor); //Descuento
                            SubTotal += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).SubTotal*DFactor);   //Subtotal
                            Retencion1 += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion1*DFactor); //Retencion1
                            Retencion2 += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion2*DFactor);  //Retencion2
                            IEPS += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IEPS*DFactor);   //IEPS
                            IVA += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IVA*DFactor); //IVA
                            ISH += (Double)0.0; //ISH
                            Total += (Double)(((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total*DFactor);  //Total
                            SaldoC += ((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Saldo-DetalleArrayList.get(i).TotalAplicado;  //Saldo
                            Referencia = "Android App Desconectado";//Referencia
                            Cliente = ((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getCliente();
                            Folio = ((CXCPDetalle)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getFolio();


        }
    }

    int i = 0;

            ContentValues Newvalues = new ContentValues();
            Newvalues.put(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo, SaldoC);


            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            newValues.put(SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SAldo, SaldoC);

    update(SqliteDB.DBhelper.TABLE_NAME_DETA ,newValues,SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_CLiente + " = " + Cliente + SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Folio + " = " + Folio,null);

    update(SqliteDB.DBhelper.TABLE_NAME, Newvalues, SqliteDB.DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + " = " + Cliente,null);

    finish();

}
```

Código `Techwatcher` el cual funciona cuando yo inserto una cantidad en el `edittext` la vaya sumando

```
private class TB_Abono_Watcher implements TextWatcher{


   Button pagar =(Button)findViewById(R.id.pago);
    private View view;
    private TB_Abono_Watcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        CXCPDetalle O_CXCPDetalle = (CXCPDetalle)((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
        if (settings.getInt("ONControlConexion",0) == 0) {
            if (O_CXCPDetalle.getViewChanged()==false) {

                O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado = ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());


                Double Total = 0.0;
                for (int i = 0; i < O_Resultado.DetalleArray.size(); i++) {
                    if (((CXCPDetalle) O_Resultado.DetalleArray.get(i)).TotalAplicado > 0) {
                        Total += ((CXCPDetalle) O_Resultado.DetalleArray.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
                    }
                }
                DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));

                if (Total == 0) {
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(true);
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(false);
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                }

                //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
                if (O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo() < O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

                }
            }
        }else
        {
            if (O_CXCPDetalle.getViewChanged()==false) {

                O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado = ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());


                Double Total = 0.0;
                for (int i = 0; i < DetalleArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (((CXCPDetalle) DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado > 0) {
                        Total += ((CXCPDetalle) DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
                    }
                }
                DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));

                if (Total == 0) {
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(true);
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pagoceros)).setEnabled(false);
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                }

                //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
                if (O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo() < O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Arrayadapter` donde lleno mi `adapter`

```
 public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CXCPDetalle> {
    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ArrayClientes) {
        super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CXCPDetalle O_CXCPDetalle = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
        }

        ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_CXCPDetalle);
        if(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado != 0){
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(String.valueOf(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado));
        }
        else {
            ((EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
        }


        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

      // ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha)).setText(dateFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getFecha()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio)).setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio());
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldoVencido()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad)).setText((numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidadTotal()) +" - "+ O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidad()));
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma)).setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion)).setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getUltimoCobroObservacion());


        double Abono = 0.0;
        Abono = O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()- O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo();
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagado)).setText(numberFormat.format(Abono));


        //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

les dejo pantalla de los detalles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que queres es identificar cada fila del listview?

Answer (score 1):

OK no estoy seguro si entendí lo que necesitas pero básicamente para modificar las vistas de cara row o filas necesitas agregarle un identificador esto es posible con el metodo [View].setTag("identificador"); esto lo puedes hacer con cualquier tipo de vista. entonces yo en to caso haría algo como esto.

```
// Antes del return colocar un identificador en este caso el folio por que veo que parece un valor unico
convertView.setTag(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio()+"_"+position);

//Devolver al ListView la fila creada
return convertView;
```

ahora ya tu fila tiene un identificador luego donde necesitas accederla puedes obtenerla de la siguiente manera para manipularla obviamente.

en tu for `View filaView = listview.findViewWithTag(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio()+"_"+position);`

ahora ya tienes la vista de una fila especifica yo la guardaria en un objeto View y obtendentria todas las demas ejemplo

TextView tw_total = (TextView) filaView.findViewById(R.id.total);

```
tw_total.setText(12.00+""); 
// osea hace con ella lo que necesites yo por lo general valido en este punto que no sea null para evitar errores
```